# Java For Loop into Recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, while-loop

```
public class For {
 public static void main(String[] args){
          for(int i=2; i<=1024; i *= 2){
           System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
      }
 }




public class While {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 1;
        while (i < 1024) {
            i *= 2;
            System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
      }
 }


public class DoWhile {
     public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 1;
        if (i < 1024) {
            do { i*=2;
                System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
            } while (i < 1024);
        }
     }
```

How would one convert the for loop/while loop so it does the same thing, but using a recursive function?

Comment: Please mark it as homework as well if it is one

Comment: If this is homework, please indicate this by adding the homework tag.

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
public class Recursive {
    public void r(int i) {
        if (i < 1024) {
            i *= 2;
            System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
            r(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recursive r = new Recursive();
        r.r(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for being not helpful. Enabling students to solve the problem at hand is helpful, to serve them the solution on a silver tray is not, IMHO. Why should Manpreet Pangli ever care listeing to his professor, when it's so cheap to get the answer from SO?

Comment: It produces different results than the examples in OPs question. Your program starts printing from 1. Multiplication by 2 should be done before println.

Comment: @Ingo: I didn't know it's homework. There's no homework tag. I think it's not fair to -1 answers not because they are not correct, but they were given to "homework questions".

Comment: @Ingo: it's hard to argue against your point, although it is a little judgemental!

Comment: Yes, @David, I care about the next generation programmers, even if they're from India. And I can't stand it if people can get away with avoidance of thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Take the loop of `main` and put it in its own function with an argument `int i`. In that function, rewrite the loop to

1. If the loop condition is false (`i >= 1024`), then `return`
2. Else, recursive call with argument `i*2`.

Call the function with argument `1` or `2`, depending on which of your programs you're rewriting (they don't entirely match).

Answer (score 1):

Recurrent loop can look like this:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      RecWhile(1);
    }

    public static void RecWhile(int i) {
       if (i < 1024) {
         i = i*2;
         System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         RecWhile(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is marked -1 not because it's incorrect, but BECAUSE it was given to a question that was not supposed to be answered this way (of course, that's not my POV; but the that's the way it is on Stack Overflow)

Comment: No, that's me, not SO. If you do not see that this can only be homework, I can't help it.

Answer (score 0):

public class Test1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test1 mainFunc = new Test1();

    int[] arr = {1,2,4,3,5,6};

    int start=0;
    int end=arr.length;
    mainFunc.callRecursiveFun(start, end, arr);
}

public int callRecursiveFun(int start, int end, int[] arr) {
    int arrLen = end;
    if(arrLen == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {

    System.out.println("Loop Index at "+start +": "+arr[start]);


    }
    return callRecursiveFun(start+1, end-1, arr);
}
```

}